# Why gcc cant complle this file containing virtual class ，but clion IDE can do that？

Tags: c++, class, gcc, gcc-warning

this is my easy code to learn vitual class，this code can be complied by clion 。

```
class BaseA{
public:
    BaseA(){};
    ~BaseA(){};
    int a;
    virtual  void fuc()=0;
};
class DrivedA:public BaseA{
public:
    DrivedA(){};
    ~DrivedA(){};
    int b;
    void fuc() override{
    b=2;
    };
};

int main() {
    DrivedA drivedA;
    drivedA.fuc();

    return 0;
}
```

this is makeLists：

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(learn_gcc_and_classvitrualtable)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(learn_gcc_and_classvitrualtable main.cpp)
```

but when i use gcc alone to compile it，it does not work with these error。
Is there anything wrong in my code or i use gcc in a wrong way...
Could you please help me?

```
[myk@MYK learn_gcc_and_classvitrualtable]$ gcc main.cpp 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccY9AVjz.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI7DrivedA[_ZTI7DrivedA]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccY9AVjz.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI5BaseA[_ZTI5BaseA]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Your class destructor should be `virtual` for abstract classes.

Comment: [myk@MYK ~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.1.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: OP, edit your question with information you believe to be relevant. That information is good to have and should be in the question.

Comment: 3q，i just try it

Comment: you need to compile c++ code with `g++` not `gcc`

Comment: @mikkkkk [edit]

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/796d1x4jE) If this is a multi-file project, you need to compile all of your *.cpp files.

Comment: @sweenish [how to reproduce on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/h6vbbo1dc)

Comment: omg！ it works！ i use g++ to compile it  ！ 3q very much！